# Inteligently remove ".0" from float output

Tags: python, json, int

I have such slice of result of my function:

```
{
    "id": "7418", 
    "name": "7.5"
}, 
{
    "id": "7419", 
    "name": "8.0"
}, 
{
    "id": "7420", 
    "name": "8.5"
}, 
{
    "id": "7429", 
    "name": "9.0"
},
```

I am doing simply:

```
[{'id': opt['size'], 'name': '{}'.format(float(opt['value']))} for opt in options]
```

I don't want to make any replacements of `".0"`, I'm interested in how to convert data correctly to:

```
{
    "id": "7429", 
    "name": "9"
}
```

Comment: My answer works perfectly now.

Comment: What exactly does `options` look like? Where does it come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Format your number with `.15g`

```
>>> format(555.123, '.15g')
555.123
>>> format(5.0, '.15g')
5
```

Though it will use the scientific exponent format for numbers close to zero:

```
>>> format(0.00001, '.16g')
1e-05
```

and for numbers that have 16+ digits before decimal point.

Note that you do not need to use the `'{}'.format()`; `format` built-in function as above works better here.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert *only `float` objects that represent integers* to `int` (i.e. convert `9.0` to `9` but leave `9.5` as it is), you can use [`float.is_integer`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#float.is_integer) to check:

```
>>> numbers = [1.0, 1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.8, 2.0]
>>> numbers = map(lambda f: int(f) if f.is_integer() else f, numbers)
>>> numbers
[1, 1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.8, 2]
>>> map(type, numbers)
[<type 'int'>, <type 'float'>, <type 'float'>, <type 'float'>, <type 'float'>, <type 'int'>]
```

---

Alternatively, if you want to apply the conversion to the string (i.e. without converting the JSON to Python objects), you could use a regular expression ([see demo](https://regex101.com/r/nN1zK0/1)):

```
>>> import re
>>> data = """
             {
                 "id": "7418", 
                 "name": "7.5"
             }, 
             {
                 "id": "7419", 
                 "name": "8.0"
             }, """
>>> print re.sub(r'"(\d+)\.0"', r'"\1"', data)

             {
                 "id": "7418", 
                 "name": "7.5"
             }, 
             {
                 "id": "7419", 
                 "name": "8"
             },
```

Note again that `"7.5"` is untouched, but `"8.0"` is replaced with `"8"`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if that is a list of dictionaries:

```
[{'id': i['id'], 'name': ['{:.1f}', '{:.0f}'][float(i['name']).is_integer()].format(float(i['name']))} for i in your_list]
```

Comment: That is rather difficult to read - it might help the OP if you added some explanation (particularly on the use of a boolean as an index).

Answer (score 0):

As type value of `name` is `String`, so we can use split method also

**Demo**:

```
input_list = [{'id': '7418', 'name': '7.5'}, {'id': '7419', 'name': '8.0'}, {'id': '7420', 'name': '8.5'}, {'id': '7429', 'name': '9.0'}]

result = []

for i in input_list:
    # Split by .
    tmp = i["name"].split(".")
    try:
        #- Type casting.
        tmp1 = int(tmp[1])
    except IndexError:
        result.apend({"id":i["id"], "name":i["name"]})
        continue
    except ValueError:
        print "Value exception, Check input:-", i
        continue

    #- Check after decimal number is equal to 0 or not.
    if tmp1==0:
        val = tmp[0]
    else:
        val = i["name"]
    result.append({"id":i["id"], "name":val})


print "Result:-", result
```

**output:**

```
Result:- [{'id': '7418', 'name': '7.5'}, {'id': '7419', 'name': '8'}, {'id': '7420', 'name': '8.5'}, {'id': '7429', 'name': '9'}]
```

Comment: Why downvote? plz explain me so I can improve my answer.

Comment: Please re-read the question - your approach is losing information the OP wants to keep.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Apology! Now done. Can you review it? I just check the other answers, not read question carefully.